# Appmaker Efficiency, do all the datasources always load?

Tags: google-app-maker

If you have a datasource where you insert information, if you don't have views that load it, will it slow down your app just to have a giant database? (Basically logging all the actions of the app).

Comment: Not sure if this applies to your question, but you can control loading of your datasources by deselecting 'Automatically load' in each datasource setting. Otherwise it's a little unclear what exactly you're after.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. The idea is I want to keep a log but I don't want the existence of a giant table to slow anything down.

Answer (score 1):

You will find more information on the Google App Maker website "[Automatically load data](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/datasources#automatically_load_data)". By default datasources load their data whenever a widget is bound to data on the datasource but can be disabled as @Markus Malessa said by clearing the checkbox on each

> Model > Datasources > DatasourceName > Automatically Load data.